# List Read and Pass it to Right Clause Functor In Prolog

Tags: prolog

This is my code:

```
functor1(Action,[Action|_]) :-
    functor2(container(Action)). 
functor1(Action,[_|OtherActions]) :-
    functor1(Action,OtherActions).
functor2(container([Abc,Def])):- 
    append([Abc],[Def],Z),write(Z).
```

Now, when I try to query,

```
functor1(X,[[first,   sign],[second, sign]]).
```

What I expect with this query is that firstly `X` should read `X = [first,sign]` and then pass to `functor2's` container so that my `functor2` can come into play. But it is continuously giving me `false`.

Comment: It does exactly what it should. Why don't you show in your question your interactive session?

Comment: Why the `append/3` call?

Comment: Thanks, there was a typo mistake in my code. My container's name was nodeValue while I wrote nodevalue in the file where it was consulted. Thanks @Boris

Comment: What @PauloMoura means is that you don't need the call to `append/3` at all: `append([A], [B], Z), foo(Z)` is simply `foo([A,B])`.

Comment: That's not the point. You already have a list with two elements, `[Abc,Def]`. The `append/3` call is just recreating it. And no, `append/3` is not a built-in predicate but a library predicate defined in the module `lists`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems fine to me... What's the problem?

```
$ swipl
Welcome to SWI-Prolog (Multi-threaded, 64 bits, Version 7.1.37)
Copyright (c) 1990-2015 University of Amsterdam, VU Amsterdam
SWI-Prolog comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY. This is free software,
and you are welcome to redistribute it under certain conditions.
Please visit http://www.swi-prolog.org for details.

For help, use ?- help(Topic). or ?- apropos(Word).

?- [f].
true.

?- functor1(X,[[first,   sign],[second, sign]]).
[first,sign]
X = [first, sign] ;
[second,sign]
X = [second, sign] ;
false.
```

Comment: Thanks, there was a typo mistake in my code. My container's name was nodeValue while I wrote nodevalue in the file where it was consulted. Thanks @repeat.